class org.eclipse.parsson.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
/**
 * Finds a substring of value that uniquely identifies it from all strings
 * in a collection.
 *
 * @param value      the target string
 * @param collection the collection of other strings
 * @return a unique substring of value, or value itself if no such substring
 *         exists
 */
public static String findUniqueSubstring(final String value,
        final Collection<String> collection) {

    return IntStream.range(1, value.length() + 1)
            .mapToObj(len -> IntStream.range(0, value.length() - len + 1)
                    .mapToObj(begin -> value.substring(begin, begin + len))
                    .filter(substring -> collection.parallelStream()
                            .noneMatch(other -> other.contains(substring)))
                    .findFirst())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).findFirst()
            .orElse(value);
}

I'm getting a runtime "java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.parsson.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String" in the "noneMatch" line.
If it's relevant: It's in a JavaFX application, using jakarta.json and its parsson implementation.
EDIT
I've found the culprit. Part of the collection was being populated by the following method.
public static <T> ObservableList<T> array(final JsonObject jo,
        final String key) {
    final List<Object>  list    = Arrays
            .asList(jo.getJsonArray(key).toArray());
    final List<T>       result  = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(item -> result.add((T) item));
    return FXCollections.observableList(result);
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster. Also add the full complete error message and stacktrace to your question.

The only way you can get that exception on that line is something has used an unsafe conversion to cast a Collection of JsonStringImpl to Collection<String> so that it can be passed as the collection argument for this method.

The ClassCastException occurs because the elements in the collection are not of type String. They are likely instances of JsonStringImpl. You need to extract the string value from these objects before performing the contains check.

You can try below and check:
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javax.json.JsonString;

public static String findUniqueSubstring(final String value, final Collection<?> collection) {
    return IntStream.range(1, value.length() + 1)
            .mapToObj(len -> IntStream.range(0, value.length() - len + 1)
                    .mapToObj(begin -> value.substring(begin, begin + len))
                    .filter(substring -> collection.parallelStream()
                            .noneMatch(other -> {
                                if (other instanceof JsonString) {
                                    return ((JsonString) other).getString().contains(substring);
                                } else if (other instanceof String) {
                                    return ((String) other).contains(substring);
                                }
                                return false;
                            }))
                    .findFirst())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).findFirst()
            .orElse(value);
}


Both the instanceof and the JasonString are reported by eclipse as invalid. Nice idea, though.
